# TFS the specified configuration database (TFS_configuration) was created using language (2057) that is currently not installed

Tags: tfs

Trying to restore TFS 2018 databases on new server, same configuration Windows Server 2016, SQL 2017 Ent.

I have restored all the databases, when I run TFS Admin Console I this error.

The specified configuration database (TFS_configuration) was created using language (2057) that is currently not installed.

SQL Server language: English (United States)
Default language on DB is: English

Log file says.......

```
[Info   @18:55:14.401] +-+-+-+-+-| Running VerifyLanguageInstalled: Verifying that the selected language is installed |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @18:55:14.402] 
[Info   @18:55:14.402] +-+-+-+-+-| Verifying that the selected language is installed |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @18:55:14.402] Starting Node: VLANGINSTALLED
[Info   @18:55:14.402] NodePath : VINPUTS/Progress/Conditional/VSQLINSTANCENAME/VSQLNOTLOCALDB/VSQLISRUNNING/VSQLCONNECT/VDBEXISTS/Conditional/VLANGINSTALLED
[Info   @18:55:14.422] Node returned: Error
[Error  @18:55:14.423] The specified configuration database (Tfs_Configuration) was created using a language (2057) that is currently not installed.
[Info   @18:55:14.423] Completed VerifyLanguageInstalled: Error
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJdAR.png)

No clue on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Check [sys.syslanguages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syslanguages-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), the `code 2057` refers to `British English` which is missing in your scenario. You should install this language before configuring the new server.

Comment: Change the default language(Database) to `British English` and try it again.

Comment: sys.syslanguages has British - LCID 2057, mslangid 1033
Tried changing language to English / British English same error.
I have set everything to English now, same error

Comment: `I have set everything to English now, same error`. What if you change everything to British English? And what's the default language for your original windows server system?

Comment: English -  original windows server system ---
I have also tired taking an image of working SQLServer and install TFS on top it, TFS 2018 (also tried Azure DevOps 2020 RC2). When I try'n use existing Congfig DB run readiness checks, I get below error.........
The specified configuration database (TFS_configuration) was created using language (2057) that is currently not installed.

Comment: Are you following the documents [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/tut-single-svr-restore-dbs?view=tfs-2018) one by one?

Comment: I'm testing the upgrade on new server, restored backed-up DB, installed TFS and trying to attached config DB.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Can it works on new server?

Comment: No, doesn't work on new server, I get same error. I guess some thing not correct on TFS_configuration? How can that be, it's our working TFS server.

Comment: I can't reproduce same issue on my side. Are those Sql all 2017 Ent? Also, can you make sure that you followed the steps documented in my shared links one by one?

Comment: I believe I figured out the root cause, when I query the config DB 

SELECT TOP (1000) [PartitionId]
      ,[ParentPath]
      ,[ChildItem]
      ,[RegValue]
  FROM [Tfs_TFSConfiguration].[dbo].[tbl_RegistryItems] where RegValue like '%2057%'
  AND ParentPath = '#\Service\Integration\Settings\'

I updated the value for "InstalledUICulture\" from 2057 to 1033 and retried the configuration, it was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **AMB** for sharing and confirming.

For error like `The specified configuration database (Tfs_Configuration) was created using a language (xxxx) that is currently not installed`, we should check the `Tfs_Configuration` database itself.

We can use SQL Query like below to find `InstalledUICulture` item:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [PartitionId]
      ,[ParentPath]
      ,[ChildItem]
      ,[RegValue]
FROM [Tfs_Configuration].[dbo].[tbl_RegistryItems] where ParentPath = '#\Service\Integration\Settings\'
```

[image]

Edit the RegValue and set it the [language ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syslanguages-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) of target Database's language and this issue would go away.